# Why doesn't the vibration of atoms due to heat in a magnetic material not induce an electromagnetic field?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

If an individual atom can have a magnetic field, and that atom is in motion due to heat why doesn't it induce a charge in a nearby conductor?

I'd think that due to the random motion of atoms due to heat, on a large scale, these magnetic fields or the electricity produced by them might cancel each other out, however, I'm wondering if even that's the case.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetism#Types_of_Magnetism This is basically what you were thinking.